# How to set GCP credential in Eclipse to run Dataflow pipeline

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a pipeline which have been developed using Java in Eclipse.

After install the Cloud SDK for Eclipse I can run the pipeline locally (direct runner) with the Dataflow configuration:

[image: dataflow]

I would also like to run it locally using maven configuration.

The problem I have if I try to execute it using maven is about credential when the pipeline try to create a pubsub subscription.

```
Exception: org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create subscription to topic projects/xxx/topics/test on project projects/xxx: 403 Forbidden

{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.154 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-12T11:19:36+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the cloud shell installed and configured. Also set the env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

---

I also have the same error if I execute the mvn command in my cmd (also gcp shell)

Comment: What are you trying to perform? What is the part of the pipeline that failed? It seams it's something like `PubsubIO`, isn't it? Other question: you obfuscated the project of the PubSub and the current project with `xxxx` and `yyyy` -> Are they different projects?

Comment: The part of the pipeline was the creation of a pubsub subscription and the begging. The  obfuscated part was the same, I will change it to put the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the below command in a shell and then try to run the job

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Alternatively you can also see here on how to setup eclipse for GCP - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse